# Django 1.8 list_display shows (None) for choicefield

Tags: python, django

In admin, I have a list_display with a choicefield.  The choicefiled shows up as None even though there is data.

```
class Evaluation(models.Model):
    xSTATUS = ((1, "PENDING"),(2, "CONFIRMED"))

    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate)
    evaluationdate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='EvaluationDate', blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Evaluator, verbose_name="Evaluator",)
    status = models.IntegerField(db_column='Status', choices=xSTATUS, blank=True, null=True)
```

My admin.py looks like this:

```
class EvaluatorEvaluationAdmin(EvaluationAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = ('candidate', 'evaluationdate', 'user', 'status', 'bankno')
```

Here's what the list looks like:

```
Candidate       Evaluationdate        Evaluator Status
Angel Badabo    May 19, 2015, 10 a.m.   mykl    (None)
Angel Badabo    Sept. 1, 2015, 4 p.m.   mykl    (None)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not setting the field, and expecting some default value to be there. What you probably want is:

```
status = models.IntegerField(db_column='Status', choices=xSTATUS, default=1)
```

Since you're setting `default`, you can get rid of `blank=True` and `null=True`.

Also, one of the big benefits of using `choices` is to do things like:

```
class Status(object):
    PENDING = 1
    CONFIRMED = 2

    CHOICES = (
        (PENDING, 'Pending'),
        (CONFIRMED, 'Confirmed')
    )

class Evaluation(models.Model):
    ...
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=Status.CHOICES)
```

This way you don't have to use/think about integers anymore, and can always access things by `Status.FIELD`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but there is data in the fields.  If I go into to the form view, I can see the data.  It's just not in the display_list.  Any ideas why not?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out...In MySQL, the field was defined as varchar.  Changed to Integer and now it shows correctly.